# Python 2 CSV writer produces wrong line terminator on Windows

Tags: python, windows, csv, python-2.x, line-endings

According to the [its documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator) csv.writer should use '\r\n' as lineterminator by default.

```
import csv

with open("test.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    rows = [(0,1,2,3,4),
           (-0,-1,-2,-3,-4),
           ("a","b","c","d","e"),
           ("A","B","C","D","E")]           

    print writer.dialect.lineterminator.replace("\r", "\\r").replace("\n", "\\n")
    writer.writerows(rows)
    print writer.dialect.lineterminator.replace("\r", "\\r").replace("\n", "\\n")
```

This prints

```
\r\n
\r\n
```

as expected. But, the created csv-file uses the lineterminator '\r\r\n'

```
0,1,2,3,4

0,-1,-2,-3,-4

a,b,c,d,e

A,B,C,D,E
```

Is this a bug or is there something wrong in my usage of csv.writer?

Python version:

> ActivePython 2.6.2.2 (ActiveState
>   Software Inc.) based on Python 2.6.2
>   (r262:71600, Apr 21 2009, 15:05:37)
>   [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

on Windows Vista

Comment: @wierob: lose the .replace(...).replace(...), use the built-in repr()

Answer (score 72, accepted):

In Python 2.x, always open your file in **binary** mode, as documented. `csv` writes `\r\n` as you expected, but then the underlying Windows text file mechanism cuts in and changes that `\n` to `\r\n` ... total effect: `\r\r\n`

From the [`csv.writer`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer) documentation:

> If *csvfile* is a file object, it must be opened with the `'b'` flag on platforms where that makes a difference.

There seems to be some reticence about actually uttering the name of the main culprit :-)

Edit: As mentioned by @jebob in the comments to this answer and based on @Dave Burton's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11235483/1224827), to handle this case in both Python 2 and 3, you should do the following:

```
if sys.version_info >= (3,0,0):
    f = open(filename, 'w', newline='')
else:
    f = open(filename, 'wb')
```

Comment: A nice "feature" is that one can still open in binary mode on platforms where it does not matter - eg, Linux, so always use binary mode.

Comment: As of 3.6, the docs now say `If csvfile is a file object, it should be opened with newline=''`

Comment: @jebob start of question, tag, start of my answer: all say Python 2.x

Comment: I am using `f = sys.stdout` and it still produces these carriage returns, even on Linux, using Python 2.7. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Also on Linux this is still producing carriage returns in my scripts under Python 2.7.

Answer (score 26):

Unfortunately, it's a bit different with the csv module for Python 3, but this code will work on both Python 2 and Python 3:

```
if sys.version_info >= (3,0,0):
    f = open(filename, 'w', newline='')
else:
    f = open(filename, 'wb')
```

Comment: This is not working for me on either Python 2 or 3, on Linux/Mac. Its still outputing Windows style newlines.

Comment: That is what it is supposed to do, user5359531. The .csv file format is supposed to consist of lines (records) terminated with Windows-style newlines: "\r\n"  If it omitted the \r that would be an error.

Answer (score 23):

To change the line terminator in Python 2.7 csv writer use

`writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = '|', lineterminator='\n')`

This is a much simpler way to change the default delimiter from \r\n.

Comment: While this works for python 2 and 3 on windows, it creates non-standard files on Linux machines: As per specification CSV files _should_ end lines with `\r\n` regardless of platform, not `\n`.

Comment: Good point, but sometimes it is necessary to violate standards to complete a specific task.