# Python3: writing csv files

Tags: python, windows, csv, python-3.x

I'm trying to use Python 3.2 on a Windows computer to write a simple CSV file, however I'm having no luck. From the [csv module documentation for Python 3.2](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

```
>>> import csv
>>> spamWriter = csv.writer(open('eggs.csv', 'w'), delimiter=' ',
...                         quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
>>> spamWriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
>>> spamWriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

produces a file with each line terminated by the byte sequence `\r\r\n`, so it looks like each line has an extra empty line when you open it with, e.g., MS Excel. This is not a "CSV file".

Note, if I try the [same example for Python 2.7](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/csv.html#csv.writer) in Python 3.2 (where the big difference is `'w'` vs `'wb'` for the file mode), I get an error when I try `spamWriter.writerow`:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in  TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

How do I write a simple CSV file from Python 3.2 on a Windows computer?

Comment: The problem seems to be Windows-specific. Works fine on Linux.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Documentation says that you should use `open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='')`

http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/csv.html#id2

Comment: Ah, it seems I picked up a slightly older version (-0.1) of the documentation (compare [3.2](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) vs [3.2.1](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.1/library/csv.html#csv.writer))

Answer (score 20):

This will work on both Python 2 and Python 3:

```
if sys.version_info >= (3,0,0):
    f = open(filename, 'w', newline='')
else:
    f = open(filename, 'wb')
```

Answer (score 7):

As [documented](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/csv.html#csv.writer) in a [footnote](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/csv.html#id3):

> `csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)`
>    If csvfile is a file object, it should be opened with newline=''.
>    If newline='' is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use \r\n linendings on write **an extra \r will be added**. It should always be safe to specify newline='', since the csv module does its own (universal) newline handling.

The following variant works on Linux and Windows:

```
spamWriter = csv.writer(open('eggs.csv', 'wb'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|',
                        quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, newline='')
spamWriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
spamWriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

Comment: I get a `TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function` when trying to do this in py34.

Answer (score 5):

To directly answer your question, you should be able to use the [lineterminator](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0305/#formatting-parameters) formatting parameter:

...so modifying this line should work (untested):

```
>>> spamWriter = csv.writer(open('eggs.csv', 'w'), delimiter=' ',
...                         quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n')
```

As for why the example doesn't work out-of-the box, kind of looks like a bug to me.

Comment: This is the only answer here that worked for me. And five years later the examples still don't work out-of-the-box :-(

Comment: This is the only answer works for me on Python 3.7, none of th above worked

Comment: This works for me also, where `newline=''` did not.

Answer (score 1):

[For Python 2.x]
This implementation of spamWriter is working for me...

```
with open('assignmentresults.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
  spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
  spamwriter.writerow(["Hullo", "World"])
```

Comment: This is not an answer for Python 3, which raises "TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface"

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this error as I was moving one of my codes from Python2.6.6 to python3.4.3

Python2.6.6(I'm trying to do some obfuscation on my csvfile)

```py
with open( os.path.join(path, name) , 'r') as mycsvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(open(newFilename, 'w'))
```

Above worked well with python2.6.6 but did not work on python3.4.3 as I was getting some utf-8 unicode errors when i tried to run the python3 file, so I made the below changes
Python3.4.4

```py
import codecs
with codecs.open(os.path.join(path, name) , 'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as mycsvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(open(newFilename, 'w'))
```

That's it, my code works fine now, basically python3 is not considering some of the unicode and we need to use the codecs import to make it working, hope it helps..

Comment: What is `mycsvfile` and what about indentation?