# KeyError when trying to use Python to select rows with a particular range of values in one column

Tags: python, csv

So I found most of the solution to my problem in this thread: [Use Python to select rows with a particular range of values in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358349/use-python-to-select-rows-with-a-particular-range-of-values-in-one-column)

But when implementing the code, I'm coming up with an error that I cannot figure out. I'm trying to extract the rows of data for subscribers only from citi bike data (info here: http://www.citibikenyc.com/system-data)

So here is the code:

```
import csv

with open("E:/Dropbox/PPS/CitiBikeData/2014_Data.csv") as input, open("E:/Dropbox/PPS/CitiBikeData/subscribers.csv", "w") as output:
   reader = csv.DictReader(input, dialect="excel-tab")
   fieldnames = reader.fieldnames
   writer_output = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames, dialect="excel-tab")
   writer_output.writeheader()
   for row in reader:
       if int(row['gender']) > 0:
          writer_output.writerow(row)
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe E:/Dropbox/PPS/CitiBikeData/csvfilter_2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Dropbox/PPS/CitiBikeData/csvfilter_2.py", line 9, in <module>
    if int(row['gender']) > 0:
KeyError: 'gender'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I understand what a KeyError is (from reading this https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError), but I can't figure out why I'm getting the error, or how to fix it.

Comment: Clarification, I used gender in the code, because any non-subscribers are coded as 0, I thought using an integer would be better than a string.

Comment: what does `print row.keys()` say?

Comment: dict_keys(['tripduration,"starttime","stoptime","start station id","start station name","start station latitude","start station longitude","end station id","end station name","end station latitude","end station longitude","bikeid","usertype","birth year","gender"'])

Comment: The file I downloaded is **not tab delimited**. You have **one key**. Note the single quotes around the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data you downloaded is **not tab delimited**. You are using the wrong CSV dialect to open it.

Remove the `dialect` parameter, the default (comma separated) is just fine for the format:

```
>>> import csv
>>> f = open("/tmp/2013-07 - Citi Bike trip data.csv")
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(f)
>>> next(reader)
{'bikeid': '16950', 'tripduration': '634', 'end station longitude': '-73.98165557', 'stoptime': '2013-07-01 00:10:34', 'end station name': '1 Ave & E 15 St', 'gender': '0', 'start station name': 'E 47 St & 2 Ave', 'start station longitude': '-73.97032517', 'start station id': '164', 'start station latitude': '40.75323098', 'end station id': '504', 'starttime': '2013-07-01 00:00:00', 'end station latitude': '40.73221853', 'birth year': '\\N', 'usertype': 'Customer'}
>>> _['gender']
'0'
```

Since the `gender` column is either `'0'` or `'1'` or `'2'`, in this case you can simply test for not equal to `'0'` and save yourself an `int()` call:

```
writer_output.writerows(row for row in reader if row['gender'] != '0')
```

This uses a generator expression to pass all filtered rows to `DictWriter.writerows()` (plural).

Comment: Thank you. I keep over looking the simple things.