# add row to existing csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, append

I want to use a function to add a row of information to an existing csv file.

`friend_info` will be a tuple including `[name, address, phone, DOB]`

I have this code

```
def add_friend(friend_info, friends_list):
    with open(friends_list, 'a') as fapp:
        writer = csv.writer(fapp)
        writer.writerow(friend_info)
```

for some reason this code is adding to the last line of the csv (I want it to start on a new line)

Comment: Part of the solution is to change `writerows` to `writerow`.

Comment: thank you. that has fixed my cell problem. how do i get it to write on a new line?

Comment: have a look [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200606/python3-writing-csv-files). If you are using Python3 perhaps you are missing the newline parameter when opening the file.

Comment: im using python 2.7. thanks for that though. im having alook. i just cant get it to start on a new line.

Comment: This question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40304504/how-do-i-add-a-new-row-of-data-to-a-csv-file-with-python/40309344#40309344

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the CSV writer object is smart enough to know that it's appending onto existing CSV data.  You're just giving it a file object and telling it to put new CSV data into that file, so it just starts writing where it can.  To start a new row, you will need to read the existing data in first, append your new row(s), then write it back out.