# Empty space in between rows after using writer in python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.3, writer

I am using csv package now, and every time when I write to a new csv file and open it with excel I will find a empty row in between every two rows.

```
filereader = csv.reader(open("tests.csv", "r"), delimiter=",")
filewriter = csv.writer(open("test_step1.csv", "w"), delimiter=",")
#Delete header
for row in filereader:
    if row[0].isdigit():
        filewriter.writerow(row)
```

[image]

Comment: open the `writer` file in `wb` mode. It is because of the `\r\n`

Comment: I tried, but got another error:  "'str' does not support the buffer interface"

Comment: open both in binary mode. `rb` and `wb` You can read a string, and write binary the same dataset

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to open the file in wb mode try:

```
import csv

filereader = csv.reader(open("tests.csv", "r"), delimiter=",")
filewriter = csv.writer(open("test_step1.csv", "wb"), delimiter=",", newline="")
#Delete header
for row in filereader:
    if row[0].isdigit():
        filewriter.writerow(row)
```

The csv.writer writes **\r\n** into the file directly.

If you don't open the file in [binary mode](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), it will write **\r\r\n** because on Windows text mode will translate each **\n** into **\r\n**.

edit:

For python 3 had to add `newline=""` to **csv.writer** as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200606/python3-writing-csv-files)

Comment: It gives me the error "'str' does not support the buffer interface" on the last line of code.

Comment: what version of python? Are you on windows?

Comment: I got it! Thanks for your help though. You have to write open("", "w", newline='') instead! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200606/python3-writing-csv-files

Comment: That's great I went to the pub I'll update my answer so you can accept if if you want

Answer (score 2):

I am using `Python 3.6` and it seems that

`csv.writer(open("test_step1.csv", "wb"), delimiter=",", newline="")`

is not correct. Rather, *`newline=""`* should added in the `open()` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that csv 1.0 in Windows (requires '\n') and MAC OS (optional). The code below will output .csv file with no spaces between next line. It works in MAC and Windows.

```
import csv
for i in range (5):
    MyList=[]
    MyList.append(i)
    cnword=0
    with open('test_step1.csv', 'a') as f:
        for item in MyList:
            if cnword != len(MyList)-1:
                f.write("%s," % item)
            else:
                f.write("%s" % item)
            cnword+=1

        f.write("\n" )  
    myList=[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add newline='' where you are opening the file.
It works for me.
e.g., csvFileName = open('file.csv', 'w', newline= '')

Comment: Better to use binary mode. But this does work.

Answer (score 0):

For those that using `pandas.DataFrame`, use `lineterminator` to remove space between row and '.write('\n') to add space between `DataFrame`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


with open('report_.csv', 'w') as f:
    for _ in range(4):  # loop here
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((3,4)))

        df.to_csv(f,
                  index=True,  # to include index
                  header=True,  # to include header
                  lineterminator='\n',  # to remove whitespace between row
                 )
        f.write('\n')  # remove this to delete whitespace between DataFrame
```

From my original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77535876/11671779)