# Storing DataFrame output utilizing Pandas to either csv or MySql DB

Tags: python, pandas

question regarding pandas:

Say I created a dataframe and generated output under separate variables, rather than printing them, how would I go about combining them back into another dataframe correctly to either send as a CSV and then upload to a DB or directly upload to a DB?

Everything works fine code wise, I just haven't really seen or know of the best practice to do this. I know we can store things in list, dict, etc

What I did was:

```
#imported all modules

object = df.iloc[0,0]

#For loop magic goes here
#nested for loop

#if conditions are met, do this
result = df.iloc[i, k+1]


print(object, result)
```

I've also stored them into a separate DataFrame trying:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'object': object, 'result' : result}, index=[0])
df2.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, mode='a')
```

The only problem with that is that it appends everything to each row, most likely do to the append and perhaps not including it in the for loop. Which is odd because the raw output is EXACTLY how I'm trying to get it into a csv or into a DB

As saying though, looking to combine both values back into a dataframe for speed. I tried concat etc, but no luck, so I was wondering what the correct format would be? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that after more research and revising, I solved my issue

Referenced this and personal revisions, this is a basis of what I did:

[Empty space in between rows after using writer in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864683/empty-space-in-between-rows-after-using-writer-in-python)

```
import csv

/* Had to wrap in a for loop that is not listed and append to file while clearing it first to remove spaces in each row*/
with open('csvexample.csv', wb+, newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Additional supporting material:

[Confused by python file mode "w+"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208206/confused-by-python-file-mode-w)