# CSV in Python adding an extra carriage return, on Windows

Tags: python, windows, csv, newline

```py
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(['hi', 'dude'])
    writer.writerow(['hi2', 'dude2'])
```

The above code generates a file, `test.csv`, with an extra `\r` at each row, like so:

```
hi,dude\r\r\nhi2,dude2\r\r\n
```

instead of the expected

```
hi,dude\r\nhi2,dude2\r\n
```

Why is this happening, or is this actually the desired behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 2 CSV writer produces wrong line terminator on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170214/python-2-csv-writer-produces-wrong-line-terminator-on-windows)

Answer (score 525, accepted):

### Python 3:

The official [`csv` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples) recommends `open`ing the file with `newline=''` on all platforms to [disable universal newlines translation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open-newline-parameter):

```py
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    ...
```

The CSV writer terminates each line with the [`lineterminator` of the dialect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator), which is `'\r\n'` for the default `excel` dialect on all platforms because that's what [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2) recommends.

---

### Python 2:

On Windows, always open your files in binary mode (`"rb"` or `"wb"`), before passing them to `csv.reader` or `csv.writer`.

Although the file is a text file, CSV is regarded a **binary** format by the libraries involved, with `\r\n` separating records. If that separator is written in text mode, the Python runtime replaces the `\n` with `\r\n`, hence the `\r\r\n` observed in the file.

See [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170214/pythons-csv-writer-produces-wrong-line-terminator/1170297#1170297).

Comment: When I use the above code, I only get \r newlines, there is no \n...

Answer (score 288):

While [@john-machin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3191811/3357935) gives a good answer, it's not always the best approach. For example, it doesn't work on Python 3 unless you encode all of your inputs to the CSV writer. Also, it doesn't address the issue if the script wants to use sys.stdout as the stream.

I suggest instead setting the 'lineterminator' attribute when creating the writer:

```
import csv
import sys

doc = csv.writer(sys.stdout, lineterminator='\n')
doc.writerow('abc')
doc.writerow(range(3))
```

That example will work on Python 2 and Python 3 and won't produce the unwanted newline characters. Note, however, that it may produce undesirable newlines (omitting the LF character on Unix operating systems).

In most cases, however, I believe that behavior is preferable and more natural than treating all CSV as a binary format. I provide this answer as an alternative for your consideration.

Comment: Can you give an example of the problem that arises if you don't "encode all of your inputs to the CSV writer"?

Comment: BEWARE: using this means `\r` is no longer escaped! Looks like this is bug in `csvwriter`, but as it stands, outputting non-conformant CSV means this is *not* the way to go.

Comment: This solved the `^M` problem for me while the accepted answer's 2 suggestions did not work.

Comment: Note: @flow2k reported https://bugs.python.org/issue36246 which already got wontfixed ("working as documented"). Perhaps writing lone CR character using csvwriter is uncommon, but this `lineterminator='\n'` solution, as the whole universal newlines idea in Python, just smells bad. I prefer to disable universal newlines with newline='' (or [this hack for `stdout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34997357/1026)). If you want to get rid of *all* CRs, not just the duplicate one, as @user985366 probably does, additionally change the dialect to `'unix'`.

Comment: BTW, I was wondering the same as @Stephen, and apparently _"it doesn't work on Python 3 unless you encode"_ refers to the 2010 version of the other answer, which recommended `open(..., 'wb')` without saying it applies to Python 2 only. I [don't believe it's actually possble to have the csvwriter work with a 'wb' file object in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5358322/1026).

Comment: Finally I think that _"it may produce undesirable newlines (omitting the LF character on Unix operating systems)."_ was supposed to mean that with the `lineterminator='\n'` hack, the `excel` dialect will use `\n` on Unix, rather than `\r\n` like [it's supposed to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49204639/1026).

Answer (score 67):

In Python 3 (I haven't tried this in Python 2), you can also simply do

```
with open('output.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(mystuff)
    ...
```

as per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer).

More on this in the doc's [footnote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3):

> If newline='' is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields
>   will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use \r\n
>   linendings on write an extra \r will be added. It should always be
>   safe to specify newline='', since the csv module does its own
>   (universal) newline handling.

Comment: Why wouldn't this be the default behavior?

Comment: @MarcStober because for the majority of opened files you want newlines translated to the platform default. You only ever want to set `newline=''` when you need full control over how line terminators are handled. Like when writing CSV data that’s compliant with the RFC. Note that it is **not the `CSV` module that opens the file here**.

Answer (score 15):

You can introduce the  **lineterminator='\n'** parameter in the csv writer command.

```
import csv
delimiter='\t'
with open('tmp.csv', '+w', encoding='utf-8') as stream:
    writer = csv.writer(stream, delimiter=delimiter, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='',  lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(['A1' , 'B1', 'C1'])
    writer.writerow(['A2' , 'B2', 'C2'])
    writer.writerow(['A3' , 'B3', 'C3'])
```

Comment: With Python 3.5.2, this was the only thing that worked for me (well, I used just `lineterminator='\n'`); the CSV module seemed to be the origin of `\r\n`. No set of arguments to `open` had any effect.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add attribute newline="\n" to open function like this:

```
with open('file.csv','w',newline="\n") as out:
    csv_out = csv.writer(out, delimiter =';')
```

Comment: No, you need to Sen`newline=''` and give the CSV module full control over how line terminators are written. The CSV format uses `\r\n` terminators *regardless of the OS default lone terminator*.

Comment: `newline=''` and `newline='\n'` have the exact same effect when opening a file for writing [according to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open-newline-parameter) so I don't think this answer is adding anything

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you use DictWriter, you will have a new line from the open function and a new line from the writerow function.
You can use newline='' within the open function to remove the extra newline.

Comment: This has nothing to do with DictWriter. DictWriter is a wrapper class around `CSV.writer()` and it doesn’t add newlines. There are no “extra newlines”.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There arent, after doing exactly that.

Comment: @Spartan: not because you are using DictWriter however. Because you are using the `csv` module, it also applies to `csv.writer()`.