# Writing directly into binary mode with csv.writer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently use the following code to create a binary file that I then directly upload into AWS S3. Now I was told it's possible to write with the `csv.writer` [directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358322/csv-modules-writer-wont-let-me-write-binary-out) into the binary mode and avoid the extra step with `io.StringIO()`. How does that work?

```
buffer = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(buffer)
writer.writerow(["a", "b", "c"])
buffer_2 = io.BytesIO(buffer.getvalue().encode())

BUCKET_NAME = 'fbprophet'
OBJECT_NAME = 'blah.csv'

s3.upload_fileobj(buffer_2, BUCKET_NAME, OBJECT_NAME)
```

Comment: python version 2 or 3?

Comment: It's `Python 3`

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358322/csv-modules-writer-wont-let-me-write-binary-out

Comment: I mentioned that link in my post, but that's where I got stuck, I don't understand how to modify my code to manage the same.

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate. @JoeyCoder is not writing a file, but rather an in-memory file-like object, so passing flags to `open` isn't going to cut it. I had an answer already written, the short of it is: your approach is fine, I don't see a way to significantly improve it. Just be sure to pass `encoding('utf-8')` because Python's default encoding is system-depedent.

Comment: That's good feedback, thank you @Thomas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've got there looks reasonable to me. The post you link to talks about writing to *files*, not in-memory streams. A file can be opened in either text or binary mode, which determines whether it operates on strings (`str`) or raw bytes (`bytes`). But the in-memory file-like objects from the `io` package aren't as flexible: you have `StringIO` for strings, and `BytesIO` for bytes.

Because `csv` requires a text stream (strings), and boto requires a binary stream (bytes), a conversion step is necessary.

I would recommend to pass the actual encoding to the `encode()` function though, to avoid falling back to Python's system-dependent default:

```
buffer_2 = io.BytesIO(buff.getvalue().encode('utf-8'))
```