# Regex and csv issues in python 2.7

Tags: python, regex, csv, screen-scraping

Used the following to fix the problems (for the remaining issues, will change my code around).  Sorry for the improper code format in my initial post.

```
import csv, re, mechanize  

htmlML = br.response().read() 

#escaping ? fixed the regex match 
patMemberName = re.compile('<a href=/foo.php\?XID=(d+) ><font color=#000000><b>(.*) </b>') 
searchMemberName = re.findall(patMemberName,htmlML)

MembersCsv = 'path-to-csv' 
MemberWriter = csv.writer(open(MembersCsv, 'wb')) #adding b fixed the \n in csv

for i in searchMemberName:
    MemberWriter.writerow(i)
    print (i)
```

---

Thank you for your time

Comment: In regex, a question mark means "zero or one of the previous character class" and a period means "any character". So, when you say .php?, you're not really looking for .php?. Try [.]php[?]

Comment: If you are using Python2 change `csv.writer(open(MembersCsv, 'w'))` to `csv.writer(open(MembersCsv, 'wb'))` (because Python2 wants csv files opened in binary).  Regardless of Python version change `MemberWriter.writerow(i)` to `MemberWriter.writerow([i])` (because `writerow` wants a row of items--currently it's interpreting each character as an item).  Finally, do you really need csv if you are going to have only one item per row?

Comment: Don't parse html with regexes.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping.

Comment: Also, this question would have been better if it were split into two questions.

Comment: @aleph_null: thank you for pointing out the obvious... had to escape '?' and '='... will update question (with a new post)

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski:  It crossed my mind, but since the problem seemed interlinked, thought to keep it in one post.  Will keep it in mind for further inquiries.

Comment: also, MemberWriter.writerow([i]) spits out a "TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable".  'wb' or just 'w' doesn't seem to make a difference on the output

Comment: don't escape the '=', but do escape the '.'

Comment: @k3rb3r05 If you are getting a `TypeError` you didn't type the parenthesis (`writerow[i]` vs `writerow([i])`.  `'wb'` really does make a difference on Python 2.7 (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191528/csv-in-python-adding-extra-carriage-return).  If you still have extra carriage returns do `writerow([i.rstrip()])`.  `rstrip` will get rid of trailing newlines in your data.

Comment: @k3rb3r05, StackOverflow has very good formatting capabilities; please [learn to use them](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).  I tried to reformat the question myself, but I can't even tell what you were trying for.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, you are right.  'wb' does make a difference.  I don't get the \n.

Comment: @AlanMoore, I used <code></code> tags.  also tried backticks (as per instructions)... using <code> tags stopped the formatter from asking me to "press ctrl+K"

Comment: Did you try pressing ctrl+K as it asked?  Or simply indenting the code blocks four spaces (which is what ctrl-K does)?  Seriously, SO's formatting easily beats any other site's that I've seen, and it's really easy to use.  Your `<code>` tags just aren't cutting it.

Comment: The ctrl+k happened when i was editing it, but didn't copy the whole code in there, just 1 line, so when I pressed 'apply' it still popped the error.  So went back to <code> tags.  Only recently noticed the difference between my post and the answers I received, so went looking... Anyway, it should be fixed now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For question 1), you have to escape the `?` in the pattern.

```
import re

htmlML = '<a href=/foo.php?XID=123 ><font color=#000000><b>user</b>'
patMemberID = re.compile('<a href=/foo.php\?XID=(\d*) ><font color=#000000><b>user</b>')

searchMemberID = re.findall(patMemberID, htmlML)
print len(searchMemberID)

for i in searchMemberID:
    print (i)
```

Then the `123` can be extracted from the string

Question 2a)

You can use `(.*?)` to replace `some string`, the `?` maens non-greedy match

Comment: please escape the period as well

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't find the proper escape sequence for Python right now. Generally, you would wrap an expression with meta-characters that should not be interpreted in "\Q...\E".

Try wrapping your string in re.escape(string). So:

```
re.compile(re.escape('<font color=#000000><b>(.*)</b>'))
```