# Python Counter results to csv file

Tags: python, csv, counter

this question is based on my pervious question: [Python list help (incrementing count, appending)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172268/python-list-help-incrementing-count-appending)

I am able to create the following output when I do print c;

```
Counter({(u'New Zealand', 174.885971, -40.900557): 1, (u'Ohio, USA', -82.90712300000001, 40.4172871): 1})
```

Which is exactly how I want and now I would like to know how I can write this to a csv file. Each row will represent a new location, lon/lat, count.

I want to loop through the counter and access these parts:
writer.writerow(["A", "B", "C"]);

A is the location like New Zealand,
B is the lat/lon,
C is the count of appearance,

How can I access count's results and get those desired parts? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `Counter` is a subclass of the standard `dict` class; you can loop over the items in the dictionary with `.iteritems()` (python 2) or just `.items()` (python 3):

```
for key, count in your_counter.iteritems():
    location, lat, long = key
    writer.writerow([location, lat, long, count])
```

This writes *four* columns, with 2 separate columns for the latitude and longitude. If you want to combine those into one column, say, as  a string with a slash between the two coordinates, just use string formatting:

```
for key, count in your_counter.iteritems():
    location, lat, long = key
    writer.writerow([location, '{}/{}'.format(lat, long), count])
```

Comment: How can I sort these ascending based on the count? @Martijn

Comment: I tried sorted(your_counter.iteritems()) but that sorts by location where I need it for count. Thanks.

Comment: Use `for key, count in reversed(your_counter.most_common()):` instead.

Comment: avoid  long as variable name, since it is a reserved word ;) just in case

Comment: @ZloySmiertniy: `long` is *not* a reserved word. It is the name of a built-in type in Python 2, one you rarely need to use directly. The type is gone altogether in py3.