# Read/Write a file where every row is a list for/from a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, io

I want to basically do this:

```
  f = open(genes_path, 'w')
  for key, genes in key_genes.iteritems():
      f.write(key)
      for gene in genes:
          f.write(",\t"+gene)
      f.write("\n")

  f.close()
```

And get this:

> key1, AT3G32920,  AT3G33187,  AT3G32940,  AT3G32930,  AT3G32980,  AT3G32960
>
> key2, AT3G32920,  AT3G33187,  AT3G32940,  AT3G32930,

Where the key can be any string (without a comma), order doesn't matter anywhere (I'm using the OrderedMultiDict from [boltons](https://boltons.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) and lists for printing convenience but it really doesn't matter, could be dict and set for all I care), and each row can have a different number of elements.

I can't seem to find any module that does this pretty simple task. DictWriter requires column/field names so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685809/python-writing-a-dictionary-to-a-csv-file-with-one-line-for-every-key-value#8685873) doesn't answer my problem.  Numpy only works with rectangular arrays and padding introduces too much unnecessary stuff. I know it's easy to write the loop yourself, but I just feel like this is something common enough it would have it's own builtin.

For the times I need to just send people big lists of things (like genes to somebody who doesn't program) so they can pull it into excel add or remove elements then send it back and I don't have to do anything else.

Anyone know of a module that has functionality for automatically reading and writing these ragged dict-of-lists files? Or if there is a good reason for this not to exist?

I'm thinking something as dead-simple as `pandas.read_csv(path, delimiter=",")` and `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv(path, delimiter=",")`.

---

**Rationale**

The reason I am being picky about it being a single function of a module and not something I could *very* easily do in pure python isn't because I'm lazy, but because when you use something from a module with good documentation it is a lot easier for someone to look at the code and figure out exactly what was intended. Even if the task is kind of trivial you're still reducing complexity of your code. I see writing your own function as something domain-specific, whereas a common read-write routine should be something you `import` and should preferably be used if available. Part of the zen of python right? So the second question really is asking "Is this a domain-specific task?", because it doesn't seem so to me.

Comment: Have you tried anything using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)?

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437727/python-write-to-excel-spreadsheet

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist that is where the DictWriter comes from so yes.

Comment: @sodiumnitrate I'm not trying to explicitly write to excel formats, I want csv/text because that is universal.

Comment: I mean, then what you're doing should work. I would write a function that does the printing, using Jake Griffin's answer below or your code, and call it whenever you need to print something.

Comment: My code does work, I just feel like that I didn't have to write it. I clarified the final question in an edit.

Comment: Expanded my comment about the csv module into an answer. I'm not sure it's a vast improvement over the simple, working code you've written. (You should try this in C some time just to appreciate the simplicity of this task in Python.) Hopefully this is in line with what you're trying to do, and if you let me know if the output file is satisfactory, I can show you corresponding read code.

Comment: I understand the difficulty of this in other languages, which is why I love python so much. I guess I got extra spoiled with numpy and pandas read functions!

Answer (score 1):

You could build each line into a string and do a single write:

```
with open(genes_path, 'w') as f:
    for key, genes in key_genes.iteritems():
        f.write("\n".join(",\t".join([key] + genes)))
```

This is still doing it yourself, but it's more succinct than the code you have posted.

Comment: Ya not really what I'm looking for. I guess it would give a good speed-up though as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well for one thing, I don't see what's so bad about your original loop (which you could turn into a function, and shorten using the [`with` context manager](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)). However, I mentioned the `csv` module because it seems to do *almost* exactly what you require, no `DictWriter` required.

I'm assuming you're starting with something like this:

```
In [4]: key_genes
Out[4]: 
{'key1': ['AT3G32920',
  'AT3G33187',
  'AT3G32940',
  'AT3G32930',
  'AT3G32980',
  'AT3G32960'],
 'key2': ['AT3G32920', 'AT3G33187', 'AT3G32940', 'AT3G32930'],
 'key3': ['AT3G32920',
  'AT3G33187',
  'AT3G32940',
  'AT3G32930',
  'AT3G32980',
  'AT3G32960'],
 'key4': ['AT3G32920', 'AT3G33187', 'AT3G32940', 'AT3G32930']}
```

So this code:

```
with open('out.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for key, genes in key_genes.iteritems():
        writer.writerow([key] + genes)
```

Produces this:

```
key3,AT3G32920,AT3G33187,AT3G32940,AT3G32930,AT3G32980,AT3G32960
key2,AT3G32920,AT3G33187,AT3G32940,AT3G32930
key1,AT3G32920,AT3G33187,AT3G32940,AT3G32930,AT3G32980,AT3G32960
key4,AT3G32920,AT3G33187,AT3G32940,AT3G32930
```

Obviously <del>if you want the keys sorted you can do that</del> your keys will be sorted, since you're using an ordered structure and I'm using a regular built-in dict. Now this is where we get into the *almost* part of your requirement. You're using `,\t` as a delimiter. If you try to do this with `csv.writer`, it will complain that delimiters should be one character. This makes sense to me because csv files are normally comma-delimited, or tab-delimited, and not both. The delimiter is only there for ease of machine processing and the machine only needs one character (that doesn't occur unquoted anywhere else) to do it.

So my final answer is: if you can live with a one-character delimiter (and for normal CSV processing, this shouldn't be a problem), use the `csv` module. Otherwise, use your short loop.

Comment: This is good as well, but like you said it's not a vast improvement as far as verbosity. The delimiter doesn't/shouldn't really matter. I'll put a function signature of my idea in the question.