# Python: Write a dictionary to a text file (CSV?) and read that text file into a dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, csv, dictionary, import, text-files

I'm a novice Python programmer so the answer may be simple.  However, I've spent several days researching this single question and I'm stumped.  This is also my first Stack Overflow post, so please be kind if I'm breaking some rule here.  :)

Using Python, I want to write two fields in multiple rows to a new text file, and on a later run read that text file into a new dictionary to reference the previous values.

I am testing code that I found here: [Example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685809/python-writing-a-dictionary-to-a-csv-file-with-one-line-for-every-key-value).  The solution provided has 64 up-votes and is marked as the best answer by the asker.  So it seems to be correct for most people.

My test code succeeds in creating an initial dictionary **mydict** and saving it to a text file.  However, when I attempt to read the text file back into a new dictionary **mydict2**, I get...nothing...nothing at all, no error message or anything, no clue, just nothing.

What am I missing here?

Here is my **test code**:

```
import csv

mydict = {1:11,2:22,3:33}
print mydict
print mydict[1]

writer = csv.writer(open('dict.csv', 'wb'))
for key, value in mydict.items():
   writer.writerow([key, value])

reader = csv.reader(open('dict.csv', 'rb'))
mydict2 = dict(reader)

print mydict2
```

Here are the contents of the **text file** that it creates:

```
1,11
2,22
3,33
```

Here are the **results displayed** when I run the test code:

```
{1: 11, 2: 22, 3: 33}
11
{}
```

As you can see in the first two lines of results output, the initial output dictionary, **mydict**, is created  correctly and displays a referenced value.  However, the third line of output displays the contents of the new dictionary, **mydict2**, which should have read the data from the text file.  However, the text file contents were somehow not read to the new dictionary, which is empty.

How can I fix this to load the text file contents into the dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not closing your files.  Your original file was not completely flushed to disk.  The `with` statement will automatically close files when the `with` block exits.

```
import csv

mydict = {1:11,2:22,3:33}
print mydict
print mydict[1]

with open('dict.csv','wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for key, value in mydict.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value])

with open('dict.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    mydict2 = dict(reader)

print mydict2
```

Output:

```
{1: 11, 2: 22, 3: 33}
11
{'1': '11', '3': '33', '2': '22'}
```

Comment: That's it!  It thought it might be file contention but couldn't find a concise example of how to close the file between the write and read statements.  

Just researched that some more.  There ISN'T a way to close a reader directly.  Suggested syntax is just what you used, the WITH statement.

Comment: @dwwheelock the problem is not file contention, but buffering: data is not saved to the disk as soon as you write it, but when there's enough to fill the buffer (if you're writing sequentially), or if you perform some operation on the file that forces it to flush the contents (seek, flush, close, ...) And yeah, you cannot close the reader (you can close the file object used by the reader, though). I have modified my original example to use `with` - I only intended to show how to read/write using dictionaries, not to teach basic file semantics...

Comment: Thank you, Ricardo, for the additional commentary and updates to your example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the following is at all *the most elegant answer,* but apparently supplying an absolute path to the .csv file helped. The following should provide you with the desired dictionary object, read from the csv you've created:

```
import csv

mydict = {1:11,2:22,3:33}
print(mydict)
print(mydict[1])

with open('C:\\Python27\\dict.csv', 'wb') as writer:
   writer = csv.writer(writer)
   for item in mydict.items():
      writer.writerow(item)

with open('C:\\Python27\\dict.csv', 'rb') as reader:
   reader = csv.reader(reader)
   for line in reader:
       mydict2[int(line[0])] = int(line[1])
   #mydict2 = {line[0]:line[1] for line in reader} ...build mydict2 as a comprehension.

print(mydict2)
```

Best Luck!

Comment: That helps.  Thanks, Jim.  I didn't even need the absolute path, but the other changes you made appear to make it work.  I'm still wondering why that simple code worked for so many people, but not for me.  If anyone else has an idea on that please chime in.

Answer (score 0):

And then there's this.  It will close the file, also.  Thanks for the coaching guys!

```
import csv

mydict = {1:11,2:22,3:33}
print mydict
print mydict[1]

f = open('dict.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(f)
for key, value in mydict.items():
   writer.writerow([key, value])
f.close()

f = open('dict.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(f)
mydict2 = dict(reader)
f.close()

print mydict2
```