# Write dictionary to csv with one line per value

Tags: python, file, csv, dictionary, key

I am quite new to Python so please excuse me if this is a really basic question. I have a Python dictionary such as this one:

`foo = {'bar1':['a','b','c'], 'bar2':['d','e']}`

I would like to write it to a csv file, with one line per **value** and the key as first element of each row. The output would be (whatever the quotation marks):

```
bar1,'a'
bar1,'b'
bar1,'c'
bar2,'d'
bar2,'e'
```

I have tried this [such as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685809/python-writing-a-dictionary-to-a-csv-file-with-one-line-for-every-key-value)

```
import csv
with open('blah.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in foo.items():
       writer.writerow([key, value])
```

but this gives the following output, with one line per **key**:

```
bar1,"['a', 'b', 'c']"
bar2,"['d', 'e']"
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `[key, value]` contains multiple "values" within `value`. Try iterating over the dictionary like this:

```
for key, values in foo.items():
    for value in values:
        writer.writerow([key, value])
```