# Pandas: Delimiter in DataFrame.from_dict()

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

Basically, I'm using Pandas to easily write my dictionary to .csv:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict, orient="index")
df.to_csv("test.csv")
```

But my .csv file looks like this:

```
key1: value1, value2
key2: value1
key3: value1, value2
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
key1: value1
kay1: value2
key2: value1
key3: value1
key3: value2
```

Is it possible to define some sort of delimiter for data in pandas? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685809/python-writing-a-dictionary-to-a-csv-file-with-one-line-for-every-key-value

Comment: What is `df.head()` ?

Comment: where do you see `df.head()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `stack`

```
df.stack().reset_index(1, drop=True).to_csv('test.csv')
```

---

```
%cat 'test.csv'

key1,value1
kay1,value2
key2,value1
key3,value1
key3,value2
```