# str has no attribuite write

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Trying to write a dictionary to a raw text file:

```
doc = {'foo':'bar'}
f = '/home/pi/Documents/samplefile.txt'
backup__file = open(f, 'a')
f.write(str(doc))
f.close
```

but getting the error str has no attribute write. How can I just dump a dictionary into a blank text file?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the write function on the path not on the file.
Try calling it on your backup__file variable. Have a look at following example.
[Python: Writing a dictionary to a csv file with one line for every 'key: value'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685809/python-writing-a-dictionary-to-a-csv-file-with-one-line-for-every-key-value)

Answer (score 0):

My bad, f is the file path, backup_file is the actual file, it should be:

```
doc = {'foo':'bar'}
f = '/home/pi/Documents/samplefile.txt'
backup__file = open(f, 'a')
backup_file.write(str(doc))
backup_file.close
```