# Initialize an empty dictionary and print to txt

Tags: python, dictionary, text

I would like to initialize an empty dictionary with the keys "001-100." I will later fill in the values.

How can I do this and then output a text file where each key:value pair is a new line in a utf-8 encoded text file? Each line should be printed as "key,value" with no quotations or spaces.

Heres what I have so far:

```
# Initialize the predictions dictionary
predictions = dict() 

#Output the predictions to a utf-8 txt file
with io.open("market_basket_recommendations.txt","w",encoding='utf8') as recommendations:    
    print(predictions, file = 'market_basket_recommendations.txt')
    recommendations.close()
```

Comment: You are filling in the values *after* printing, or before?

Comment: lol before i eventually print the dictionary, i will add the values

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just add the key value pairs as they're generated? Are there some keys that won't get values but still need to be printed?

Comment: The only reason I want to add the values later is that I dont have them yet. Please see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45448508/frequency-based-recommendations?noredirect=1#comment77858283_45448508)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Creating an empty dict

Use `dict.from_keys()`. It's specifically for building an empty dict.

```
predictions = dict.fromkeys("{:03}".format(i) for i in range(1, 101))
# {'001': None,
#  '002': None,
#  '003': None,
#  '004': None,
# ...
```

---

#### Printing on their own lines

What's more natural than using the standard `print` function? You can do that with `redirect_stdout`.

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

with open("market_basket_recommendations.txt", 'w') as file:
    with redirect_stdout(file):
        for k, v in p.items():
            print("{},{}".format(k, v))
#
# In market_basket_recommendations.txt:
#
# 001,None
# 002,None
# 003,None
# 004,None
# ...
```

Comment: There should be no spaces anywhere in the file. It seems like this solution would but a space between k and v on each line?

Comment: I've implemented that change. Are you just trying to produce a CSV file? There's a built-in library for that.

Comment: No, the output must be a text file

Comment: A CSV file is still text.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it has to be .txt

Comment: That's just a file extension; it's trivial. I encourage you to explore [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685809/python-writing-a-dictionary-to-a-csv-file-with-one-line-for-every-key-value) about printing out dicts in CSV format.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
d = {i:0 for i in range(1, 101)}

f = open('the_file.txt', 'a')

for a, b in d.items():
   f.write(str(a)+" "+b+"\n")

f.close()
```

Comment: I believe that the "correct" way to write the file should be using a print statement as opposed to write.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Initialize the predictions dictionary
predictions = dict({
        'a': 'value',
        'another': 'value',
    }
) 

#Output the predictions to a utf-8 txt file
with open("market_basket_recommendations.txt", "w", encoding='utf8') as recommendations:
    for key in predictions:
        recommendations.write(key + ',' + predictions[key] + '\n')
```

output:

```
another,value
a,value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('outfile.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for k, v in predictions.items():
        f.write(k + "," + v)
        f.write('\n')
```