# Writing CSV file Python3 issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm using poloniex trader api to get realtime market ticker info. It works perfect on console. When ever i request for market ticker in returns i get this `{'last': '0.07269671', 'high24hr': '0.07379970', 'quoteVolume': '71582.56540639', 'isFrozen': '0', 'lowestAsk': '0.07277290', 'percentChange': '-0.00551274', 'id': 148, 'low24hr': '0.07124645', 'highestBid': '0.07269671', 'baseVolume': '5172.41552885'}`

Problem is it's only storing item name/list name such as - `low24hr, lowestAsk, highestBid etc`. Not their value like -`low24hr : 0.07124645`

```
polo = Poloniex()
ticker_data = (polo('returnTicker')['BTC_ETH'])

out = csv.writer(open("myfile.csv","w"), delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,)
out.writerow(ticker_data)
print(ticker_data)
```

Here is what my csv file looks like- 
[image: ImageView]

[image: ImageView]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  There isn't enough information in your post for us to help you.  Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `out.writerow(ticker_data)` takes only the keys of the dictionary and writes them to the file. Try to use a `csv.DictWriter`:

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    # Pass the keys of the `ticker_data` as the fieldnames.
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=ticker_data, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    # Write the fieldnames.
    writer.writeheader()
    # Write the values.
    writer.writerow(ticker_data)
```

Comment: as a beginner this makes better sense to me friend (hug)

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('my_file.csv', 'w') as f:
    for key, value in ticker_data.items(): f.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(key, value))
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685809/python-writing-a-dictionary-to-a-csv-file-with-one-line-for-every-key-value).

Comment: Don't use a list comprehension if you don't want to create a list. Just use a normal for loop.