# export dictionary to csv file in python

Tags: python, dictionary, export-to-csv

[image]

I am trying to export an output file as a CSV file.

I have 15 columns and 400 rows.

In my code, I stored data in the dictionary file, which means that I have one dictionary for each column.

So I want to get a CSV file which includes all dictionary in the same file.
I tried to use a (for) loop in order to do that, but it did not work.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Add your peace of code

Comment: give [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) a read

Comment: can you post a sample format of your data?

Comment: What do you mean by 'one dictionary for each column' ? Each dictionary have one key for each row ? You can't use a list instead ?

Comment: Please share sample dictionary of few columns.

Answer (score 1):

## use Pandas  libray

let us Assume your dictionary is like this:

```
    my_dict = {'key1': '1', 'key2': 'b', 'key3': '123'}
```

To tackle your problem use :

```
    import pandas as pd

    (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=mydict, orient='columns')
    .to_csv('file_name.csv', header=False))
```

See [Ivan Calderon's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45472788/6996446) Answer  for more information.!!

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the variable as per your need. This should work.

```
def WriteCsv(csvFileName, csvFieldNames,  row=None ):

    import csv
    import os 
    if row:
        if os.path.exists(csvFileName):

            f_handle = open(csvFileName, 'a')
            csvWriter = csv.DictWriter(f_handle, fieldnames=csvFieldNames)
        else:

            f_handle =  open(csvFileName, 'w+')
            csvWriter = csv.DictWriter(f_handle, fieldnames=csvFieldNames)
            csvWriter.writeheader()
        try:
            csvWriter.writerow(row)
        finally:
            f_handle.close()

for row in dict_data:
    WriteCsv(csvFileName="Names.csv",csvFieldNames=csv_columns,row=row)
```