# Using python csv - Merging rows based on column

Tags: python, csv

Current table

[image]

Desired result

[image]

Not getting any results with this right now. Not sure where to go from here.

```
import csv
csv_dict = {}
with open("Test.csv", "r") as source:
    reader = csv.reader(source)
    header = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] in csv_dict:
            csv_dict[row[0]] += row
        else:
            csv_dict[row[0]] = row
        print (row)
```

Comment: `csv_dict[row[0]] += row`: you don't want to do that. You want to add the non blank values (except for the first row) to the dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are trying to do doesn't work because you're adding the *whole row* each time.

You want to filter out blanks and accumulate values on one key.

There are 2 ways (with 2 different outcomes):

### 1) standard accumulation, regardless of positions

```
import csv,collections
csv_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open("test.csv", "r") as source:
    reader = csv.reader(source)
    header = next(reader)
    for key,*rest in reader:
        csv_dict[key] += filter(None,rest)

print(csv_dict)
```

You get this dictionary: `{'b': ['2', '4'], 'a': ['1', '2', '3', '4']}`

### 2) accumulation but with positions matching the original position of the non-blank value

In that case, you have to increase the list size if the index doesn't fit in.

```
import collections,csv

csv_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open("test.csv", "r") as source:
    reader = csv.reader(source)
    header = next(reader)
    for key,*rest in reader:
        for i,r in enumerate(rest):
            if r:
                d = csv_dict[key]
                while i>=len(d):
                    d.append("")
                d[i] = r

print(csv_dict)
```

that yields:

```
{'a': ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'b': ['', '2', '', '4']}
```

In both cases, [there are several solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685809/writing-a-dictionary-to-a-csv-file-with-one-line-for-every-key-value) to write this dictionary in a resulting csv file (using a `csv.DictWriter`, `csv.writer`, `pandas` module).

Comment: csv module works too. pandas is cool. Once you have the dictionary, the rest is already covered on this site.