# Writing a text file with rows that have two words separated by comma from a while loop

Tags: python, file, dictionary, file-io, while-loop

```
dictionary = {}
name = input("Name: ")

while name: #while the name is not blank
    age = input("Age: ")
    dictionary[name] = age
    name = input("Name: ")

print("Thank you, bye!")

f = open("1ex.txt","w")
f.write( str(dictionary) )
f.close()
```

So I have this code, it does what I want, but I cant seems to figure it out how can I write the file, so that it would have not a dictionary, but smth like this:

```
Jane, 25
Jim, 24
```

I tried putting everything into a list, but it doesn't work out for me.

Comment: If you want it saved as a csv you could use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685809/writing-a-dictionary-to-a-csv-file-with-one-line-for-every-key-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dictionary = {}
name = input("Name: ")

while name: #while the name is not blank
    age = input("Age: ")
    dictionary[name] = age
    name = input("Name: ")

print("Thank you, bye!")

# Open the file
with open("1ex.txt","w") as f:
    # For each key/value pair in the dictionary:
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        # Write the required string and a newline character
        f.write(f"{k}, {v}\n")
```