# one extra line getting added when i open CSV file on window. This is observed only when i send CSV file as attachment to email

Tags: python, linux, excel, email, csv

I have python script that generates CSV file by reading multiple csv files as input. from linux machine i am sending that csv file as an email attachment using mail command. when i open that attached file on window's machine using MS Excel its adding one extra blank line line between each line present in csv. when i open that file in linux using  vi editor its fine only four lines are present in csv file. Its more strange when i copy that file using winSCP from linux to window and open in MS Excel file is good no extra blank lines.
Is there anything wrong in mail command or my script is not generating correct csv file.

can anybody find something wrong that i am missing in this process.

Comment: can u paste the code about how the CSV files are being read?

Comment: @PrahaladDeshpande I don't think he reads the CSV with Python - they are supposed to be opened in MS Excel on a Windows platform.

Comment: Why negative voting i have tried all the ways like python open option w, wb, w+r ... i have added lineterminator=\n while opening  file for writing. inserted sep=, as separator in csv file. nothing is working thats why i posted this question.

Comment: @LukasGraf am reading CSV input files with python only. i will post whole script wait.

Comment: Python 3 or Python 2?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski i am using python 2.6 i have posted whole script which reads input csv and generates result.csv

Comment: I don't see a problem with the Python code. So where you save the mail attachment on the Windows box, and open that with notepad or a hex editor, what sort of line endings does it have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be running into trouble with different platform specific line endings.

Windows uses `\r\n`, Macs (before OS X) used `\r`, UNIX uses `\n`.

I suggest to inspect the .csv that causes problems with a hex editor or `hexdump`:

```bsh
# hexdump -C test.csv
00000000  31 3b 32 3b 33 0a 61 3b  62 3b 63 0a              |1;2;3.a;b;c.|
0000000c
```

(The `0a` in here is a newline (`\n`). Windows' `\r\n` would be `0d 0a`).

In order to (testwise) convert files from UNIX to Windows line endings (and vice-versa), you can use the [dos2unix / unix2dos tools](http://dos2unix.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: i tried to print hexdump i can see 0a most of the times. so in my case \n is newline character i guess. if yes then it should work on windows.

Answer (score 1):

There are discussions related to the CSV writer behavior with respect to the occurrence of additional new lines. Also, the behavior seems to be different from 2.7 and 3.0 versions.

[This](http://bugs.python.org/issue7198) link talks about the occurrence of such an issue. However [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191528/csv-in-python-adding-extra-carriage-return) SO question gives a solution.

As per y understanding it is always good to take control of how newline has to be written by the CSV writer by doing something like

```
csv.writer(sys.stdout, lineterminator='\n')
```