# CSV file with unexpected double space Python

Tags: python, csv

Using Python 2.7 to open up file a turn it into a dictionary with row 0 as key and row 3 over as values. Then open up file b, for the matching ID number in row 0 to append the other columns for the match. Then convert back into a list and merge two CSV's.

At the end add headers and save as "output.csv."

And example of what I was expecting:

File a:

```
1234, 14/12/2,123.4,
5618, 13/1/12,23.4,
9143, 15/2/14,222.4,
```

File b:

```
1234,abc,cda
9143,nda, bad 
5618, ede, fpc
```

(dream) output:

```
payment date, payment amount, other id, other other id, payment status, payment type
 14/12/2,123.4,1234,abc,cda, Received, Recurring
 13/1/12,23.4,9143,nda, bad, Received, Recurring 
 15/2/14,222.4,5618, ede, fpc,Received, Recurring
```

(actual) output:

```
ID, payment date, payment amount, other id, other other id, payment status, payment type
1234, 14/12/2,123.4,1234,abc,cda, Received, Recurring

 5618, 13/1/12,23.4,9143,nda, bad, Received, Recurring 

 9143, 15/2/14,222.4,5618, ede, fpc,Received, Recurring
```

The code:

```
import csv

#create a dict from first csv, with clearing solution id as key
with open("DDS.csv", "rb") as f:
    first = {rows[0]: rows[3:] for rows in list(csv.reader(f))}

# compare second csv, append rank, add received recurring columns
with open("report.csv", "rb") as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        if row and row[0] in first:  # row[0] = clearing solution id
            first[row[0]].append(row[1])  # row[1] = rank
            first[row[0]].append(row[2])
            first[row[0]].append('Received')
            first[row[0]].append('Recurring')


# convert dict back to list
merged = [(k,) + tuple(v) for k, v in first.items()]

# write list to output csv
with open('output.csv', "w") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames =['ID', 'Payment Date', 'Payment Amount', 'Other ID','other other ID', 'Payment Status', 'Payment Type'])
    writer.writeheader()
    csv.writer(f).writerows(merged)
```

Bonus points:
How do I delete the first column from the output CSV?

Thanks

Comment: The immediate issue you're seeing with the extra blank lines should be solved by adding a `lineterminator='\n'` argument to `csv.DictWriter()`, on Windows the csv module uses a lineterminator of `\r\n` by default, see similar questions e.g [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19618856/1222578)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the first just don't add `(k,)` to your tuple and remove 
'ID' from your fieldnames. You don't need to be creating another writer to write the rows `csv.writer(f).writerows(merged)`?:

```
merged = [tuple(v) for k, v in first.items()]
with open('output.csv', "w") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames =['Payment Date', 'Payment Amount', 'Other ID','other other ID', 'Payment Status', 'Payment Type'])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(merged)
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using classical python string manipulation instead of csv module.

For example using `rows.replace(' ','').split(,)[0]` instead of `rows[0]` should solve the space problem.