# How to write CSV output to stdout?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout

I know I can write a CSV file with something like:

```
with open('some.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
```

How would I instead write that output to `stdout`?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

[`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) is a file object corresponding to the program's standard output. You can use its `write()` method. Note that it's probably not necessary to use the `with` statement, because `stdout` does not have to be opened or closed.

So, if you need to create a `csv.writer` object, you can just say:

```
import sys
spamwriter = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
```

Comment: On Windows, this results in an extra carriage return character after each row.

Comment: You can give the csv.writer constructor a lineterminator option:`writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, lineterminator=os.linesep)`

Comment: `lineterminator=os.linesep` makes no sense, as on Windows this is no-op. You probably meant `lineterminator='\n'`, which is also NOT an obviously correct solution (see comments on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17725590/1026)). [Reconfiguring sys.stdout to disable universal newlines handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34997357/1026) is a possible alternative.