# go back one character during csv write

Tags: python, csv, xlrd

I'm trying to convert xls sheets to CSV files.

```
workbook1 = xlrd.open_workbook(path+'diseaseData.xls')
for sheet in workbook1.sheet_names():
    sh = workbook1.sheet_by_name(sheet)
    csvFile = open('//....../disease-'+sheet+'.csv', 'w')
    wr = csv.writer(csvFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
        # print (sh.row_values(rownum))
        wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))
    csvFile.close()
```

it works but the outputted CSV's have an empty line after each line

```
"ID","Caption","Sequela type","Visible",""

"infection","Infection","infection","1",""

"acute","Symptomatic infection","acute","1",""

"asymptomatic","Asymptomatic infection","sequela","1",""

"ards_long","Permanent disability due to ARDS","sequela","1",""

"fatalAcute","Fatal cases","sequela","1",""
```

How can I tell the wr.writerow that it must overwrite the last character?

I think this would eliminate the extra carriage returns.

I tried `.strip('\n')` but

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: Try `[s for s in mystrings if s != '\n']` or if you want to eliminate all strings containing newlines, `[s for s in mystrings if '\n' not in s]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to go back one character. Just use the lineterminator argument for csv writer.

```
wr = csv.writer(csvFile, lineterminator='\n')
```

Other thread about this behavior e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613698/python-write-csv-adding-extra-carriage-return).

Comment: Awesome, always let the library do the string processing for you unless you have a good reason not to! I knew there was a good answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

If the strings in the list need to have `\n` removed from them, use `strip`:

```
>> a = ["\nfrog", "\ncow", "\nsnake"]
>> print map(str.strip, a)
['frog', 'cow', 'snake']
```

If the list needs to have `\n` removed from it, try `remove` for a single item or a list comprehension like this for all of them:

```
b = [x for x in a if not x == "\n"]
```

`remove` has the advantage/disadvantage of modifying the original list.  You could call `remove` on the list `while "\n" in list`.

Comment: I love `map` the functional paradigm but it's more idiomatic and considered more readable in python to use comprehensions, i.e. `[x.strip() for x in a]`

Comment: it's the list that has a `\n` too much, not each element of the list. (because here a list is a CSV line and an element of the list is 1 value) I tried `wr.writerow(map(str.strip, sh.row_values(rownum)))` but it doesn't work, same error