# Decoding a Python 2 `tempfile` with python-future

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, character-encoding, temporary-files

I'm attempting to write a Python 2/3 compatible routine to fetch a CSV file, decode it from `latin_1` into Unicode and feed it to a `csv.DictReader` in a robust, scalable manner.

- For Python 2/3 support, I'm using `python-future` including imporing `open` from `builtins`, and importing `unicode_literals` for consistent behaviour
- I'm hoping to handle exceptionally large files by spilling to disk, using `tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile`
- I'm using `io.TextIOWrapper` to handle decoding from the `latin_1` encoding before feeding to `DictReader`

This all works fine under Python 3.

The problem is that `TextIOWrapper` expects to wrap a stream which conforms to `BufferedIOBase`. Unfortunately under Python 2, although I have imported the Python 3-style `open`, the vanilla Python 2 `tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile` still of course returns a Python 2 `cStringIO.StringO`, instead of a Python 3 `io.BytesIO` as required by `TextIOWrapper`.

I can think of these possible approaches:

1. Wrap the Python 2 `cStringIO.StringO` as a Python 3-style `io.BytesIO`. I'm not sure how to approach this - would I need to write such a wrapper or does one already exist?
2. Find a Python 2 alternative to wrap a `cStringIO.StringO` stream for decoding. I haven't found one yet.
3. Do away with `SpooledTemporaryFile`, decode entirely in memory. How big would the CSV file need to be for operating entirely in memory to become a concern?
4. Do away with `SpooledTemporaryFile`, and implement my own spill-to-disk. This would allow me to call `open` from python-future, but I'd rather not as it would be very tedious and probably less secure.

What's the best way forward? Have I missed anything?

---

Imports:

```
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division,
                    print_function, unicode_literals)
from builtins import (ascii, bytes, chr, dict, filter, hex, input,  # noqa
                  int, map, next, oct, open, pow, range, round,  # noqa
                  str, super, zip)  # noqa
import csv
import tempfile
from io import TextIOWrapper
import requests
```

Init:

```
...
self._session = requests.Session()
...
```

Routine:

```
def _fetch_csv(self, path):
    raw_file = tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile(
        max_size=self._config.get('spool_size')
    )
    csv_r = self._session.get(self.url + path)
    for chunk in csv_r.iter_content():
        raw_file.write(chunk)
    raw_file.seek(0)
    text_file = TextIOWrapper(raw_file._file, encoding='latin_1')
    return csv.DictReader(text_file)
```

Error:

```
...in _fetch_csv
    text_file = TextIOWrapper(raw_file._file, encoding='utf-8')
AttributeError: 'cStringIO.StringO' object has no attribute 'readable'
```

Comment: I had a similar problem and didn't find a better solution than to write separate code for Python 2 and 3 and then detect which version you're running on.

Comment: @cbare Yea, I suspected it might come down to that. Any chance you could post your solution?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure whether this will be useful. The situation is only vaguely analogous to yours.

I wanted to use [NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) to create a CSV to be encoded in UTF-8 and have OS native line endings, possibly not-quite-[standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), but easily accommodated by using the Python 3 style io.open.

The difficulty is that NamedTemporaryFile in Python 2 opens a byte stream, causing [problems with line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191528/csv-in-python-adding-an-extra-carriage-return). The solution I settled on, which I think is a bit nicer than separate cases for Python 2 and 3, is to create the temp file then close it and reopen with io.open. The final piece is the excellent [backports.csv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/backports.csv) library which provides the Python 3 style CSV handling in Python 2.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
from builtins import str
import csv, tempfile, io, os
from backports import csv

data = [["1", "1", "John Coltrane",  1926],
        ["2", "1", "Miles Davis",    1926],
        ["3", "1", "Bill Evans",     1929],
        ["4", "1", "Paul Chambers",  1935],
        ["5", "1", "Scott LaFaro",   1936],
        ["6", "1", "Sonny Rollins",  1930],
        ["7", "1", "Kenny Burrel",   1931]]

## create CSV file
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp:
    filename = temp.name

with io.open(filename, mode='w', encoding="utf-8", newline='') as temp:
    writer = csv.writer(temp, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, lineterminator=str(os.linesep))
    headers = ['X', 'Y', 'Name', 'Born']
    writer.writerow(headers)
    for row in data:
        print(row)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: This method actually voids all `NamedTemporaryFile`'s checks which were intended to make sure nobody else claims that filename. You could also use `tempfile.mktemp()` whose docstring states that "this function should not be used".
A probably-better approach is to re-open your file by fileno, without closing it. I'll post it as a separate answer once I test that a bit.

Comment: @MarSoft I'm not sure I understand. Does NamedTemporaryFile give you any guarantees beyond a uniquely named file? Do you have exclusive access until the file is closed, which you then lose? I'd be curious to know if I'm asking for trouble with the above approach.

Comment: you can look in the docs for `tempfile.mktemp()` which generates a name for temporary file but does not create the file. That function is deprecated because it is a security risk: `This function is unsafe and should not be used.  The file name refers to a file that did not exist at some point, but by the time you get around to creating it, someone else may have beaten you to the punch.`
I will now add more details in a separate answer.

Comment: UPD: just noticed that you instruct `NamedTemporaryFile` to not delete the file. Then you probably don't have that security risk. Although it might be possible on some platforms (like `nt`) to remove other user's file once it is not opened anymore..

Answer (score 1):

@cbare's approach should probably be avoided. It indeed works but here is what happens with it:

1. We use `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()` to create temporary file. We then remember its name.
2. We leave `with` statement and that file is closed.
3. Now that the file is closed (but not removed) we open it again and open it with `io.open()`.

At first glance it looks okay, and at second glance too. But I am not sure if on some platforms (like `nt`) it might be possible to remove the other user's file when it is not opened - and then create it again but have access to its contents. Please somebody correct me if this is not possible.

Here is what I would suggest instead:

```
# Create temporary file
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tf_oldstyle:
    # get its file descriptor - note that it will also work with tempfile.TemporaryFile
    # which has no meaningful name at all
    fd = tf_oldstyle.fileno()
    # open that fd with io.open, using desired mode (could use binary mode or whatever)
    tf = io.open(fd, 'w+', encoding='utf-8', newline='')
    # note we don't use a with statement here, because this fd will be closed once we leave the outer with block
    # now work with the tf
    writer = csv.writer(tf, ...)
    writer.writerow(...)

# At this point, fd is closed, and the file is deleted.
```

Or we could directly use `tempfile.mkstemp()` which will create file and return its name and fd as a tuple - although using `*TemporaryFile` is probably more secure & portable between platforms.

```
fd, name = tempfile.mkstemp()
try:
    tf = io.open(fd, 'w+', encoding='utf-8', newline='')
    writer = csv.writer(tf, ...)
    writer.writerow(...)
finally:
    os.close(fd)
    os.unlink(name)
```

#### And to answer the original question regarding SpooledTemporaryFile

I would try subclassing `SpooledTemporaryFile` under python2 and overriding its `rollover` method.

*Warning:* this is not tested.

```
import io
import sys
import tempfile

if sys.version_info >= (3,):
    SpooledTemporaryFile = tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile
else:
    class SpooledTemporaryFile(tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile):
        def __init__(self, max_size=0, mode='w+b', **kwargs):
            # replace cStringIO with io.BytesIO or io.StringIO
            super(SpooledTemporaryFile, self).__init__(max_size, mode, **kwargs)
            if 'b' in mode:
                self._file = io.BytesIO()
            else:
                self._file = io.StringIO(newline='\n')  # see python3's tempfile sources for reason

        def rollover(self):
            if self._rolled:
                return
            # call super's implementation and then replace underlying file object
            super(SpooledTemporaryFile, self).rollover()
            fd = self._file.fileno()
            name = self._file.name
            mode = self._file.mode
            delete = self._file.delete
            pos = self._file.tell()
            # self._file is a tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper.
            # It caches methods so we cannot just replace its .file attribute,
            # so let's create another _TemporaryFileWrapper
            file = io.open(fd, mode)
            file.seek(pos)
            self._file = tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper(file, name, delete)
```