# Issue CSV module python

Tags: python, csv

I created a program to write a simple .csv (code below):

```
opencsv = open('agentstatus.csv', 'w')
a = csv.writer(opencsv)
data = [[agents125N],
    [okstatusN],
    [warningstatusN],
    [criticalstatusN],
    [agentdisabledN],
    [agentslegacyN]]
a.writerows(data)
opencsv.close()
```

The .csv looks like this (it's with empty rows in the middle, but it's not a problem):

```
36111

96

25887

10128

7

398
```

Now I am trying to read the .csv and store each of this numbers in a variable, but without success, see below an example for the number 36111:

```
import csv 

with open('agentstatus.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    f = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in f:
        firstvalue = row[0]
```

However, I get the error:

```
line 6, in <module>
    firstvalue = row[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Could you support me here?

Comment: Are all your values meant to be a single record in the csv? I think `csv.writer` has a `writerow` method that writes the values as a single entry that might be better. `row[1]` would then return `okstatusN`.

Comment: Hello, no, actually would be nice if they were in 6 records, one per row/line.

Comment: actually, i am already using the writerows..

Comment: `writerow` vs `writerows`. One takes a list of values and puts them onto one line in the file, the other takes a list of lists and runs `writerow` on each list in turn. Your values are each in their own list so get added as new lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSV in Python adding an extra carriage return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191528/csv-in-python-adding-an-extra-carriage-return)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you're writing 6 rows into a csv file, with each row containing one column. To make a single row with six columns, you need to use a list of values, not each value in its own list.

ie change

```
data = [[agents125N], [okstatusN], [warningstatusN], [criticalstatusN], [agentdisabledN], [agentslegacyN]]
```

to

```
data = [[agents125N, okstatusN, warningstatusN, criticalstatusN, agentdisabledN, agentslegacyN]]
```

(a list containing one list of six values). Writing this with `csv.writerows` will result in

> 36111, 96, 25887, 10128, 7, 398

`row[1]` in your reading loop will return 96.

Comment: yeah, i got it :), trying now to attribute the varibale to row[1]

Comment: I dont understand, even changing the data format o csv, when I run the code  `import csv 

with open('agentstatus.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    f = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in f:
        firstvalue = row[0]` I am still getting    ` firstvalue = row[0]
IndexError: list index out of range` error

Comment: Print `row` before the `firstvalue =` line and see what's it's trying to access? Have you looked at the file that was written?

Comment: data file looks fine: `36098,96,26324,9678,7,399` and if i print i have this `['36098', '96', '26324', '9678', '7', '399']
[]`

Comment: It looks like it's adding an empty line at the end which is causing problems. Are you using windows or linux (not sure if that'd cause a difference but new lines are different).

Comment: i am using windows. So it seems that is that .. making problem since beginning, any idea what could be done? thanks a lot!

Comment: Add something like `if not row: continue` at the top of the for loop?

Answer (score 2):

Your file contains empty lines, so you need to check the length of the row:

```
values = []
for row in f: 
    if len(row) > 0:
        values.append(row[0])
```

`values` is now `['36111', '96', '25887', '10128', '7', '398']`

Comment: still getting an error: line 6, in <module>
    for row in f:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: maybe will try to use diferent method to write the csv. and insert correctly the data per row, without empty rows in middle. what you think? thanks.

Comment: `f` is the reader as in your code above `f = csv.reader(csvfile)`, right?