# Error in writing a list to a CSV column in python

Tags: python, csv

I want to write a list to the third column of a csv file.

```
list = ['cat', 'dog', 'duck', ..., 'goat']

writer = csv.writer(f)
for val in list:
    writer.writerow([val])
```

However the output I get always has one row empty in between as follows.

```
cat

dog

duck

...

goat
```

I want to know how to make it correct as well as to have the list in the third column of csv.

Comment: If you want the values in the third column, then what would the first two columns be?

Comment: Oh sorry, its a typo. its a list. I corrected it. I want to have first two columns to have numbers starting from zero.

Comment: Try this: `writer.writerow([val.strip()])`

Comment: The issue is that an extra carriage return is added in between the lines causing it to be - `cat\r\r\ndog....` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## With Blanks

You can easily add empty columns by adding "None" entries in the list argument to writerow(). A fully working example follows:

```
import csv
import tempfile

list = ['cat', 'dog', 'duck', 'goat']

name = None
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=False) as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for val in list:
        writer.writerow([None, None, val])

    name = f.name

with open(name, 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    print(contents)
```

The result is:

```
,,cat
,,dog
,,duck
,,goat
```

## With Numbers

In order to have numbers starting from zero instead of blanks you can modify like so:

```
import csv
import tempfile

list = ['cat', 'dog', 'duck', 'goat']

name = None
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=False) as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    pos = 0
    for val in list:
        writer.writerow([str(pos), str(pos+1), val])
        pos += 2

    name = f.name

with open(name, 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    print(contents)
    print(dir(f))
```

This results in the following:

```
0,1,cat
2,3,dog
4,5,duck
6,7,goat
```

Comment: Did you try your code with a normal file? Does it still correctly write out the results without extra newline?

Comment: Yes, I tried it and I don't get any extra newlines.

Comment: Excellent, Good answer. However, I still get the extra new line prob.

Comment: To use a regular file, just replace "tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=False)" with "open('temp.csv', 'w')".

Comment: You might not be trying in windows. or you might not be using python 3

Comment: @David Checkout the duplicate bug, for details on the new line prob

Comment: To avoid the extra line breaks (probably you're using Windows?), see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191528/csv-in-python-adding-an-extra-carriage-return

Comment: Thanks a lot all. It solved. I simply used newline='' in file open as given in that question. with open('output.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(mystuff)
    ...