# How to write data in each row in csv file without overwriting in python

Tags: python, csv

I want to write data in each row in csv file without overwriting. With this code I am able to write the data in every second row of the file. Please any help.This is the part of the code Im using these code

```
.... 
dfl_origin= [dfl_origin_X,dfl_origin_Y]
import csv
c = csv.writer(open("C:/Config/Output/box1.csv","a"))
c.writerow([dfl_origin[0],dfl_origin[1]])
....
```

And the output is these
[image: output]

So . Why the second data is not written into second row? Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at contents of `box1.csv` in a text editor, such as Nodepad or Sublime Text? It probably contains a blank line at the bottom of file. If you're using Unix/Linux systems, what's the output of `wc -l box1.csv` without running this script?

Comment: Im not using  Unix/Linux system. Working on Windows. When open with Excel second row is empty. But should not be like that, I saw other python data scv file open with Excel and each raw is full filled with data. Something in the code is missing. But can not find what

Comment: This seems like a line endings issues Windows vs. Unix. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191528/csv-in-python-adding-an-extra-carriage-return). tl;dr: try opening the file in binary mode: `'ab'`

Comment: Try using file mode `ab` instead of just `a`.

Comment: 'ab' doesn't help. Its the same issue

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? Show us some sample data from your dataframes.

Comment: Also did you try the second answer on the page I linked? `c = csv.writer(open("C:/Config/Output/box1.csv","ab"), lineterminator='\n')`

Comment: the second answer c = csv.writer(open("C:/Config/Output/box1.csv","ab"), lineterminator='\n' works

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?