# What exactly are the csv module's Dialect settings for excel-tab?

Tags: python, excel, csv

> *The csv module implements classes to read and write tabular data in CSV 
>   format. It allows programmers to say, “write this data in the format
>   preferred by Excel,” or “read data from this file which was generated
>   by Excel,” without knowing the precise details of the CSV format used
>   by Excel.*

What if I **want** to know??

All kidding aside, I want to know specifically which attributes and settings would create the dialect [`csv.excel_tab`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.excel_tab)

`Dialect.delimiter`
A one-character string used to separate fields.

`Dialect.doublequote`
Controls how instances of quotechar appearing inside a field should themselves be quoted.

`Dialect.escapechar`
A one-character string used by the writer to escape the delimiter if quoting is set to QUOTE_NONE and the quotechar if doublequote is False.

`Dialect.lineterminator`
The string used to terminate lines produced by the writer. It defaults to '\r\n'.

`Dialect.quotechar`
A one-character string used to quote fields containing special characters, such as the delimiter or quotechar, or which contain new-line characters.

`Dialect.quoting`
Controls when quotes should be generated by the writer and recognised by the reader. It can take on any of the QUOTE_* constants (see section Module Contents) and defaults to QUOTE_MINIMAL.

`Dialect.skipinitialspace`
When True, whitespace immediately following the delimiter is ignored. The default is False.

`Dialect.strict`
When True, raise exception Error on bad CSV input. The default is False.

Comment: Try `import csv; help(csv.excel)` in an interactive interpreter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Going straight to the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/csv.py#L55) of `Lib/csv.py`, `excel-tab` has all the properties of `excel`, plus a tab-delimiter.

```
class excel(Dialect):
    """Describe the usual properties of Excel-generated CSV files."""
    delimiter = ','
    quotechar = '"'
    doublequote = True
    skipinitialspace = False
    lineterminator = '\r\n'
    quoting = QUOTE_MINIMAL
register_dialect("excel", excel)

class excel_tab(excel):
    """Describe the usual properties of Excel-generated TAB-delimited files."""
    delimiter = '\t'
register_dialect("excel-tab", excel_tab)
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for showing me the _source_. I _wanted_ to look for the source. I _thought_ I _could_ dig in to find it, but just couldn't get there.

Comment: Among other ways, can always use `import csv` -> `csv.__file__`.  I like to copy and paste that path and open it right in any browser