# How to remove a cells from column

Tags: python

It's quiet simple - when I run this simple syntax in my text editor:

[image: Syntax]

Then the output is:

[image: output]

The problem is how can I remove the column to get this:

[[image: csv create without python]

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add your code in text format and not as images? This would make your question much easier to read. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open your file in binary mode: `with open(file, 'w+b') as csv_file:`

or set `newline` to empty string: `with open(file, 'w+', newline='') as csv_file:`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3191811/6685140