# How to skip \n symbols when I export to csv?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a list that has this form

```
[['url', 'date', 'extractRaw', 'extractClean'], ['https://www.congress.gov/crec/2017/01/09/CREC-2017-01-09-senate.pdf', '20170109', 'UR\n\nIB\nU\n\nU\n\nE PL\n\nNU\n\nCo', '20170109', 'URIBUUE PLNUCo'], ['https://www.congress.gov/crec/2017/01/09/CREC-2017-01-09-senate.pdf', '20170109', 'UR\n\nIB\nU\n\nU\n\nE PL\n\nNU\n\nCo', '20170109', 'UURIBUUE PLNUCo']]
```

I'm exporting it to a CSV with this code

```
def exportCSV(flatList, filename):
    with open(filename+".csv", "wb") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(flatList)

exportCSV(textExport,'textExport')
```

This version follows the new line and I end up with a CSV that reads to a new line for every one of the `\n` symbols.

My desire is to get each entry in the list on its own separate line. It would look something like this

```
url    date     extractRaw    extractClean
https://www.congress.gov/crec/2017/01/09/CREC-2017-01-09-senate.pdf    20170109    UR\n\nIB\nU\n\nU\n\nE PL\n\nNU\n\nCo    URIBUUE PLNUCo
https://www.congress.gov/crec/2017/01/09/CREC-2017-01-09-senate.pdf    20170109    UR\n\nIB\nU\n\nU\n\nE PL\n\nNU\n\nCo    URIBUUE PLNUCo
https://www.congress.gov/crec/2017/01/09/CREC-2017-01-09-senate.pdf    20170109    UR\n\nIB\nU\n\nU\n\nE PL\n\nNU\n\nCo    URIBUUE PLNUCo
```

Does `writer.writerows()` support that? Can I get it to ignore the new line symbols?

It's not a duplicate. The `\n` is part of the block of text and the file is opened as `'wb'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSV in Python adding an extra carriage return, on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191528/csv-in-python-adding-an-extra-carriage-return-on-windows)

Comment: The Python 3 documentation says to open files for output with `open(filename, mode='w', newline='')`. Try that.

Comment: I should've mentioned it's python 2.7. It looks like newline didn't exist for 2.7

Comment: On the chance that you have the option, you could export to a more capable format, like .xlsx or .ods.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, some of your strings contain *\n* *char*s.

"***\n***" (or *ASCII* ***0x0A*** (*10*) or ***LF*** (*line feed*)), is a special char that gets interpreted when such a string is written. In order to solve your problem, you could either:

- Make your strings *raw* (don't know how feasible is that). Anyway for more details check [[Python 2]: String literals](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)
- Manually **escape** any "***\***" (*bkslash*) character preceding "*n*", so that "*\n*" becomes a string that consists of **2** *char*s ("*\*" and "*n*"). Translated into code, you should replace your last line, by (assuming that *textExport* contents was pasted at the beginning):

  ```py
  escapedTextExport = [[item.replace("\n", "\\n") for item in row] for row in textExport]

  exportCSV(escapedTextExport, "textExport")
  ```

Comment: This is really helpful. I'm just going to get rid of the `/n` symbol from the text block.