# Writing data scraped from a HTML table to a CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to figure out what will be the next step to convert my webscrape to CSV.

I've tried putting every column into individual lists, but I feel like this is not the solution.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2018/passing.htm'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for row in tb.find_all('tr'):
    i = row.get_text()
    print(i)
```

Comment: next step: `import csv`

Comment: better put every row in separated list and then use module `csv` and `writerow(list)` or `writerows(list_of_lists)`

Comment: It's not obvious to me what the expected result should look like. Can you provide a snippet of the final CSV you want (and explain how you got it)? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen the expected result is for the csv to look like the table.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks. Do you want the headers every 30 lines, or just at the top? `tb` is not defined in your code, BTW.

Comment: @ggorlen just the top

Comment: OK--does my answer work for you?

Comment: @ggorlen yes it does. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
import csv      #quite crucial

final_table = []
for row in tb.findall('tr'):
    next_line = row.get_text()
    final_table.append([next_line])

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(final_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `csv` module. We'll grab the headers with `soup.find("tr").find_all("th")`, then loop over the body and write it to the text file. The first cell of each row is a `<th>`, so we need to handle that separately and prepend it to the `<td>` data. Note that the staggered headers every 30 lines are omitted.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2018/passing.htm"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow([x.get_text() for x in soup.find("tr").find_all("th")])

    for row in soup.find_all("tr"):
        data = [row.find("th").get_text()] + [x.get_text() for x in row.find_all("td")]

        if data: 
            writer.writerow(data)
```

Output (just the top few rows):

```
Rk,Player,Tm,Age,Pos,G,GS,QBrec,Cmp,Att,Cmp%,Yds,TD,TD%,Int,Int%,Lng,Y/A,AY/A,Y/C,Y/G,Rate,QBR,Sk,Yds,NY/A,ANY/A,Sk%,4QC,GWD
1,Ben Roethlisberger,PIT,36,QB,16,16,9-6-1,452,675,67.0,5129,34,5.0,16,2.4,97,7.6,7.5,11.3,320.6,96.5,71.0,24,166,7.10,7.04,3.4,2,3
2,Andrew Luck*,IND,29,QB,16,16,10-6-0,430,639,67.3,4593,39,6.1,15,2.3,68,7.2,7.4,10.7,287.1,98.7,69.4,18,134,6.79,6.95,2.7,3,3
3,Matt Ryan,ATL,33,QB,16,16,7-9-0,422,608,69.4,4924,35,5.8,7,1.2,75,8.1,8.7,11.7,307.8,108.1,68.5,42,296,7.12,7.71,6.5,1,1
4,Kirk Cousins,MIN,30,QB,16,16,8-7-1,425,606,70.1,4298,30,5.0,10,1.7,75,7.1,7.3,10.1,268.6,99.7,58.2,40,262,6.25,6.48,6.2,1,0
```

[Check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191528/csv-in-python-adding-an-extra-carriage-return-on-windows) if you see extra newlines in the CSV result on Windows.