# Issue pulling list from CSV file in Python (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, csv

My code takes the input and successfully writes to the 'data.csv' file, but whenever more than one number is entered as the initial input (e.g. '98765 12345') I get `IndexError: list index out of range` on the very last line.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
x = raw_input('Enter numbers separated by a space: ')
new_FONs = [[int(i)] for i in x.split()]

with open('data.csv', 'a+') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(new_FONs)

with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    all_FONs_str = [line.split() for line in f]
    all_FONs = [[int(FON[0])] for FON in all_FONs_str]

for FON in new_FONs:

    # Count the occurence of this number in the CSV file
    FON_count = all_FONs.count(FON)

    if FON_count == 1:
        print('once')

    elif FON_count == 2:
        print('twice')
```

Comment: What's the last element of `all_FONs_str ` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191528/csv-in-python-adding-an-extra-carriage-return-on-windows

Comment: @JuanC should just be a number as string?

Comment: @bboooooyintheuk it's not.  You should either look at the csv file itself, or print(all_FONs_str) before the last line to see the problem.  The link I provided in the comments will fix this issue.

Comment: @Chris I think it is because it's adding an extra line that's just blank in the csv file... and for some reason when I do a for loop it runs from last value to first, and this is encountering the blank. Is there a way to fix this? Will add for loop to original question too

Comment: @bboooooyintheuk did you try adding newline='' to your open calls as suggested in the link?

Answer (score 0):

Limiting the last loop to the penultimate element should do:

```
x = raw_input('Enter numbers separated by a space: ')
new_FONs = [[int(i)] for i in x.split()]

with open('data.csv', 'a+') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(new_FONs)

with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    all_FONs_str = [line.split() for line in f]
    all_FONs = [[int(FON[0])] for FON in all_FONs_str[:-1]]
```