# Why are my csv output rows separated with csv.writer?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to clean a csv file that I downloaded from google sheets. But my output when I write it to a new csv file has the rows separated

code:

```
with open(output_file, 'w') as new_file:
    writer = csv.writer(new_file)
    writer.writerow(["Name", "Id", "Agent", "WinLoss", "Fees",
                     "Rakeback", "Rebate", "Net"])
    for row in reader:
        fees = row["Total"]
        total_rebate = rebate(row["Winning+fees"], rebate_rate)
        winloss = get_winnings(row["Winning+fees"], row["Total"])
        rakeback = calculate_rakeback(fees)
        net = calculate_net(winloss, total_rebate, rakeback)
        writer.writerow([row["Player Name"], row["Player ID"], row["Agent Name"], winloss,
                         fees, rakeback, total_rebate, net])

    new_file.close()
```

[screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7kLi.png)

Comment: can you show expected  output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the standard windows line seperator `\r\n` is written to the csv file in text mode. But then the Python runtime replaces the `\n` with `\r\n` so that in the end the file containt `\r\r\n` at every line break, hence the extra line.

To solve this problem set the `lineterminator` attribute when creating the writer:

`writer = csv.writer(new_file, lineterminator='\n')`

You can read more about the problem in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191528/csv-in-python-adding-an-extra-carriage-return-on-windows) thread.

**Edit**

As noted by Mark Tolonen the recommended way to go about this would be to add `newline=''` in the open statement, so `with open(output_file, 'w', newline='') as new_file:`

Also see the [csv documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) for more info.

Comment: While this works, the best solution is to follow the csv documentation and use `newline=''` in `open`.