# python creates empty lines between lines when writing to file

Tags: python, csv, file

Maybe this is a simple question but I can't find in the community

I tried to write in files

```
import csv
f_out = open('filename.csv','w')
csvwriter = csv.writer(f_out)
li = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
csvwriter.writerow(li)
csvwriter.writerow(li)
csvwriter.writerow(li)
csvwriter.writerow(li)
f_out.close()
```

And instead of this :

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

I get this :

```
1,2,3,4,5,6

1,2,3,4,5,6

1,2,3,4,5,6

1,2,3,4,5,6
```

And 2 another empty line at the end of the file.

anyone can say where is my problem?

Comment: I'm getting the output as expected

Comment: Same, this piece of code works as expected. No extra lines.

Comment: did you tried `writerows`? `csvwriter.writerows([li] * 4)`

Comment: Are you on [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191528/csv-in-python-adding-an-extra-carriage-return-on-windows)?

Comment: @deadshot ty. you are using python3.8 or python 2? I tried in PowerShell too and get the same problem.

Comment: @forgetso yes, bro. I am on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is quite easy. In the open method you need to add a parameter newline=''.

```
import csv
f_out = open('filename.csv','w',newline='')
csvwriter = csv.writer(f_out)
li = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
csvwriter.writerow(li)
csvwriter.writerow(li)
csvwriter.writerow(li)
csvwriter.writerow(li)
f_out.close()
```

I think this should help you...
For further details you can refer [CSV Writer Documentation link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer)

Comment: oh. Thank you. It works. sorry but I have another little question. in the end of this file, I get one empty line. what can I do to don't have an empty line in the end of the file?