# Python Module CSV adds a blank line between writen lines in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I see some unsolved related questions, so... here I am to toss a coin and see if anyone can help me!

I´m using the CSV module to create csv files, but for each created line, the code adds one blank line.

The csv module has 2 ways to write a csv file: list mode and ordered dict mode. Both create the same problem.

I pasted here a "list mode" code.

```
from csv import writer
 
with open('movies.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer_csv = writer(file)
    movie = None
    writer_csv.writerow(['Title', 'Genre', 'Lenght'])
    while movie != 'finish':
        movie = input('Movie name: ')
        if movie != 'finish':
            genre = input('Genre: ')
            lenght = input('Lenght: ')
            writer_csv.writerow([movie, genre, lenght])
```

Everything works fine, but the extra blank line.

The result is...

```
Title,Genre,Lenght

Bourne Identity,Action,120

Bourne Supremacy,Action,125

Ultimatum Bourne,Action,128
```

And the desired result is...

```
Title,Genre,Lenght
Bourne Identity,Action,120
Bourne Supremacy,Action,125
Ultimatum Bourne,Action,128
```

Thank's for any help!

Comment: This solved the undesired line break: `with open('movies.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:` (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191528/csv-in-python-adding-an-extra-carriage-return-on-windows))

Comment: I don't see extra blank lines in the file when I run this code.  Are you running on Windows?  And how are you opening the file to see the extra blank lines?

Comment: _Every single example_ in the csv documentation opens the file using something like this: `with open('eggs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:` - the `newline=‘’` isn’t there for no reason. Read the documentation  https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-csv

Comment: Thank you my friends, great help!
Yes John, the problem is the windows, which affects somehow the whole lib CSV. Hope Windows 11 comes for good!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a newline -

```
with open('movies.csv', 'w',newline='') as file:
```

By default, `newline` is `'\n'`

Comment: Thank you very much! Great help, appreciated!