# Writing a Python list into a single CSV column

Tags: python, csv, writer

I have a list of numbers that I want to put in a single column in a .csv file. The code below writes the values across a single row. How can I change the code so that Python writes the each value on a separate row? Thanks.

```
        with open('returns.csv', 'wb') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(daily_returns)
```

Comment: ISTM a CSV file with only column doesn't need a csv.writer.  Just use ``f.writelines([ret + '\n' for ret in daily_returns])``

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: Perhaps this is farfetched, but the `ret` values could contain `'\n'` characters or delimiters that would need quoting.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

With Python3, open the file in `w` mode:

```
with open('returns.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for val in daily_returns:
        writer.writerow([val])
```

With Python2.6+, open the file in `wb` mode:

```
with open('returns.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for val in daily_returns:
        writer.writerow([val])
```

Comment: I think the open call should only be `open('returns.csv', 'w') as f:`

Comment: Thanks. I tried the same code, but my last line read writer.writerow(val) and I got the error "Sequence Expected." I didn't realize I needed the brackets.

Comment: @Casey: I would tend to agree, but since the OP wrote it, I assume he knows what he's doing.

Comment: @unutbu, Casey: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170214/pythons-csv-writer-produces-wrong-line-terminator/1170297#1170297  ... the OP has evidently read the docs :)

Answer (score 11):

**Alternate solution:** Assuming daily_returns is the name of the list you wish to write as a column in a CSV file, the following code should work:

```py
with open('return.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(zip(daily_returns))
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me in Python 3.x.

Answer (score 5):

Just for the record:

I'm using Python 3.2 and I could only get the following to work

```
with open('returns','w')as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f,lineterminator='\n')
    for val in returns:
        writer.writerow([val])
```

Comment: In Python 3, you should open files using the `newline=''` parameter, as explained in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/csv.html#csv.writer).

Answer (score 3):

For writing a single column, I would recommend avoiding the `csv` commands and just using plain python with the [str.join() method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
    with open('returns.csv', 'wb') as f:
        f.write("\n".join(daily_returns))
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I used 'w' instead of 'wb'. Thanks!