# CSV Reader different outputs on Ubuntu and Windows - Python

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-2.7, csv

I have a file called Some.csv which has a field (column) which has values like

> 1000, 2000, .... 39000.

I wanted only the files with 39000 so I wrote the following python script

```
import os
import csv

with open('Somenew.csv', 'w') as fw:
  writr = csv.writer(fw, delimiter=',')
  with open('Some.csv','r') as fr:
    reader = csv.reader(fr, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
      if row[2] == '39000':  writr.writerow(row)
```

Now when this executes on Windows it Somenew.csv looks like this

> xxxx, xxxx, 39000, xxxx, xxxx
>
> yyyy, yyyy, 39000, yyyy, yyyy

But when executing on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04LTS) there is no extra newline added.

Is there any reason for this? Is it perhaps because of the compiler?

Comment: It's because Windows uses `\r\n` for line endings in text files instead of `\n`. The simple fix is to read & write your CSV files as binary files, but there are other options in Python 3. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170214/pythons-csv-writer-produces-wrong-line-terminator/1170297#1170297

Comment: 2.7.something (probably 10). Thanks that makes sense.

So change 'r' and 'w' to 'rb' and 'wb'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `wb` mode for `csv` files if you are using Python 2.x:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer

> If csvfile is a file object, it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your file in binary mode.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3191811/6176113) answer may help.