# Python: Writing new line to csv in for loop

Tags: python, csv

I have the following problem. I have a for loop, in which i want to add always the newcoming element of a list to a new line in a csv file. But something is wrong with my code. If i open the file, there is alwys a space between the rows and the list brackets are also existing.

My code extract:

```
    allParameterCombi.append([fRC_Network1.jc,fRC_Network1.radius,fRC_Network1.frcSize, fRC_Network1.percent[0],fRC_Network1.percent[1],fRC_Network1.distType, fRC_Network1.ID])

    with open('parameterCombinatons.csv','a') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=";")
        writer.writerow([allParameterCombi[count3-1]])
    count3 = count3 +1
```

How it looks like opened: 
[image]

Comment: could you give me an output via notepad? not excel. also, a hint for the structure of `allParameterCombi` may be fruitful.

Comment: Why have you wrapped `allParameterCombi[count3-1]` in an extra set of `[]`?

Comment: yeah, that was definetly a mistake! now it recognize the columns. But the space between the lines still exists.

Comment: Explicitly open the file as binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open your file in binary mode ("`ab`") before passing them to `csv.writer` like this:

```
with open('parameterCombinatons.csv','ab') as csv_file:  #python3 open('parameterCombinatons.csv','a',newline='')
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! What is the difference between a and ab?

Comment: @Varlor  `b` means open file in _binary_ format in python2.

Comment: refer to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170214/python-2-csv-writer-produces-wrong-line-terminator-on-windows/1170297#1170297) for more details.